# Expression template, addition of a variable and a value

Tags: c++, templates, addition, expression-templates

I have an expression template which adds a variable with a constant in a given expression. I want to convert that to add the variable with any given number. 
Structs for constants and variables:

```
struct Var {
  int operator () (int v) { return v; }
};

struct  Constant {
  int c;
 Constant (int d) : c (d) {}
  int operator () (int) { return c; }
};
```

This is the expression struct:

```
template < class L, class H, class OP >
struct DBinaryExpression {
    H h_;
  L l_;

  DBinaryExpression (L l, H h) : l_ (l), h_ (h) {}
  int operator () (int d) { return OP::apply (l_ (d), h_(d)); }
};
```

This is the addition struct:

```
struct Add {
  static int apply (int l, int h) { return l + h; }
};
```

This is the operator template:

```
template< class A, class B >
DExpression<DBinaryExpression<DExpression<A>, DExpression<B>, Add> >
operator + (DExpression<A> a, DExpression<B> b)
{
  typedef DBinaryExpression <DExpression<A>, DExpression<B>, Add> ExprT;
  return DExpression<ExprT>(ExprT(a,b));
}
```

This is the header file:

```
int main (void)
{
  typedef DExpression <Var> Variable;
  typedef DExpression <Constant> Literal;

  Variable x ((Var()));
  Literal l (Constant (50));

  int a=10;


 evaluate (a, x+l); 

 return 0;
}
```

This is actually not my code but i have added all of the basic arithmetic operations to the code.

Any ideas guys? I am new to *C++* templates and i don't really get much of it.

Comment: You're not actually asking a question.

Comment: @EiriniTelevantou replace `50` with `7` in your `main`, and your constant becomes `7` instead of `50`...

Comment: Where is DExpression defined?

Comment: I think he is asking how to elimiate needing to make the constant.  In that case he just needs an operator+ that takes a DExpression and an short, long, int, float, double, etc. as well as the one that takes two Dexpressions.